# Modify existing resource with Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is it possible to modify an existing resource with Helm? E.g. I already have a running ingress that I'd like to add annotations to?

Comment: You could modify the chart and upgrade the release you installed with the modified version of the chart.

Comment: If the resource was created with helm within the same release. However, this is not the case here. The resource is created manually.

Comment: I see. Then the answer is no - resources can't be managed (installed as part of a release) and not managed by Helm (installed with Helm hooks or not by Helm at all), not both. See [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/4423).